# Calculate mean val from column excluding 'None' values

Tags: python, math, multiple-columns, mean, nonetype

I have a large array of tab delimited data. I'd like to calculate the mean values for each column. The problem is some values are 'None' and I'd like to perform the calculation and exclude these data points.

The data structure looks like this:

```
0.0     0.5     0.0     0.142857142857  0.0     0.0
0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0             0.0     0.0
0.0     0.8     0.0     None            0.0     0.0
```

I'm using this code. Not sure how to add the condition into this:

```
data = [float(l.split('\t')[target_column_val]) \
           for l in open(target_file, 'r').readlines()]
mean = sum(data) / len(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` has a default mode of `r` or `read`. So, I do not add the `r` here in `open`. We get a file object from this as `f`. `f` is iterable, so we loop through all the lines in `f`.

After we do so, we can split the line by spaces, so that we why we use `for item in var.split()` which gives us a list of strings, that have been been formed by splitting the line in `f`.

We use `if != 'None'` because this is one way of getting rid of `"None"` values here. And in the end we append the `float(item)`. because we want floats and not strings.

```
with open('targe_file.txt') as f:
    final_list = [float(item) for var in f for item in var.split() if item != 'None']  # None is a string in this instance.

print final_list
```

Try the above code, you *can* add if statements to a list comprehension *after* the iterable.

You can then calculate the mean like so:

```
mean = sum(final_list) / len(final_list)
```

We can use the `sum` function to add up all the floats in a list. The `sum` function takes in an iterable object, something like a `list` (our case) or a `tuple`. and `len` gves you the length of a list.

Comment: I seem to have made a mistake in the answer, please wait for me to update.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `map` and `zip` functions. Here is some sample (modify it to serve your needs)

```
>>> from numpy import mean
>>>
>>> def safe_float(s):
...     try:
...         return float(s)
...     except ValueError:
...         return s
...
>>> def filter_none(lst):
...     return filter(lambda x: x<>'None', lst)
...
>>> source = ['0.0 0.5 0.0 0.142857142857 0.0 0.0',
...           '0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0',
...           '0.0 0.8 0.0 None 0.0 0.0']
>>>
>>> data = [map(safe_float, l.split()) for l in source]
>>> filtered_columns = map(filter_none, zip(*data))
>>> print map(mean, filtered_columns)
[0.0, 0.43333333333333335, 0.0, 0.071428571428499996, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `if` clauses in comprehensions:

```
[l for l in (stuff) if l != 'None']
```

Looking at what I think you're trying to do, I think this should do it:

```
with open(target_file) as infile:
    col = (line.split('\t')[target_column_val] for line in infile)
    data = [float(x) for x in col if x != 'None']
    mean = sum(data)/len(data)
```

The problem with the answer in my comments is that I think it shifts the columns left and can cause you to get values you may not want.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how would I incorporate the if clause for each element in the l.split('\t') array? Eg in each row there may be 1 or more 'None' values and I'd like to pass over these.

Comment: I just realized something that might complicate things. What is `target_column_val`?

Comment: Aside from that, if you replace `l.split()` with something like `[val for val in l.split() if val is not None]` then that will filter all `None` values out of the list. I just don't know if that will mess up your indexing.

Comment: @ChadMiller None needs to be a string.